# $(document).scroll is not firing in IE8 only

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, scroll

I have a site running some javascript.  In IE8 only, the $(document).scroll is not firing when you scroll with or without the mousewheel.
Code snippet below:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
        //do something on scroll
      });
```

Is there a specific reason this function won't fire in IE8?  I have searched online with no success.

Thanks for all advice and tips in advance!!!!!

Comment: Another day, another IE-related issue to work around

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try using `window`:

```
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    //do something on scroll
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

For a lot of areas, IE ties the event to window rather than document as other browsers will. $(window).scroll(function(e) {}); is what you're after here. Should generally also work in most other browsers too, but if not, use a check on the navigator to find IE and use window or document based on that Boolean.